# What tag should I use for a question asking the meaning of a word/phrase?

Tags: discussion, tags

What tag should be used for a question asking the meaning of a word/phrase? Since there is already [word-choice](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice) and [word-usage](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-usage), would [word-meaning](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-meaning) be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, [word-meaning](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-meaning) should be used instead of [meaning](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning), as it is more regular to the other tags.

Also, I think the tag [meaning-in-context](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning-in-context) should be used only if the meaning of the word/sentence changes depeding of the context. Almost all questions using this tag do not provide a context, so they should be retagged [word-meaning](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-meaning). (Maybe we don't need [phrase-meaning](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-meaning) since it is very rare that words get a specific meaning when grouped together).